# Set .htaccess at localhost and hide index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I wanna ask about .htaccess that could be change the url to be more simple. I have the url in my localhost like this:

```
localhost/spsb/index.php
```

and

```
localhost/spsb/index.php?page=student
```

The question is:

1. How can i change the url above being:

`localhost/spsb`

and

```
localhost/spsb/student
```

2. And where is the correct place to save the .htaccess file?

Thank's a lot for advice
I have been searching a lot everywhere but no one can solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Use URL Rewriting

**For an Apache server:**

First, you must activate the rewrite module 
([How to active mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/fr/mod/mod_rewrite.html))

Add those lines to your htaccess to enable rewrite engine

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On
```

And this line to rewrite the url as you want

```
RewriteRule ^spsb\/?$ spsb/index.php
RewriteRule ^spsb/([a-zA-Z]+)$  spsb/index.php?page=$1  [L]
```

**For a Nginx server:**

Put these lines in "Location" scope:

```
if (!-e $request_filename)
{
    rewrite ^spsb\/(.*)$ spsb/index.php?page=$1;
}
```

Note: the location of .htaccess is relative to his level into the site structure, if he is inside the first level site/dir/ the contained rules are limited to site/dir structure

To be unlimited, i suggest to put it into the document root
...Or you can put the rules directly into you vhost configuration

**How to check errors:**

- First have you restarted your server to apply the activated rewrite
  modules
  (rules from htaccess dont require a restart, only module
  modification)
- Add following lines to your htaccess after "RewriteEngine On":

  RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/{your_log_site...}" <-- put your path

  RewriteLogLevel 7
- Check by a "tail -f /var/log/apache2/you_log_site.errorlog" to see if
  an error appear at resfresh page

Comment: Hey @MTroy Thank's a lot for the advice... I'll try now

Comment: I have been just try but not working even i already turning on the 

`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` in httpd.conf

and i also put the .htaccess in the project folder of htdocs

How about this?

Comment: I didn't make a log... How identify the wrong way in your opinion?

Comment: Ok, i'm talking about apache2 log, in you /var/log/apache2/
look my answer, i've updated the how to